# How to jump in Box2D with LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, jumping

I am making a 2D platformer in LibGDX with both Ashley and Box2D.

I have it so, that the `PlayerControllerSystem` watches for the jump key being pressed:

```
// Jumping
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keybindings.KEY_JUMP)) {
    entity.add(new JumpingComponent());
}
```

This works like a charm. Every time I press the jump key the `PlayerJumpingSystem` fires up:

```
/**
* System used for the player jumping mechanism
* @author Tim
*/
public class PlayerJumpingSystem extends IteratingSystem {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final static String TAG = PlayerJumpingSystem.class.getName();

    // Variable declaration
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static final Family family = Family.all(
            PositionComponent.class,
            VelocityComponent.class,
            PhysicsComponent.class,
            PlayerComponent.class,
            JumpingComponent.class).get();

    public PlayerJumpingSystem () {
        super(family);
    }

    @Override
    protected void processEntity (Entity entity, float deltaTime) {
        PositionComponent position = Mappers.position.get(entity);
        VelocityComponent velocity = Mappers.velocity.get(entity);
        PhysicsComponent physics = Mappers.physics.get(entity);

        if (velocity.y > 0) {
            // We are ascending
            physics.body.applyLinearImpulse(0, -Constants.JUMP_FORCE, position.x, position.y, true);
        }

        if (velocity.y < 0) {
            // We are descending
            physics.body.applyLinearImpulse(0, Constants.JUMP_FORCE, position.x, position.y, true);
        }

        else if (velocity.y == 0) {
            entity.remove(JumpingComponent.class);
            Gdx.app.log(TAG, "JumpingComponent removed");
        }
    }

}
```

It gives very weird jumping behaviour. Does anyone know how to implement jumping with Box2D in a good way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this:

## In your hud class

```
public jumpButtonPressed = false;
buttonJump.addListener(new InputListener() {
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        jumpButtonPressed = true;
        return true;
    }
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        jumpButtonPressed = false;
    }
});
```

## In controll buttons

```
public void updateInput(float dt) {
    if ((Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.UP) || Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.W)) || hud.jumpButtonPressed == true) {
        hud.jumpButtonPressed = false;
        if (player.getState() != player.State.JUMPING) {

            player.b2body.setLinearVelocity(player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x,0);
            player.b2body.applyForceToCenter(0, 160f, true);

        } 
    }
}
```

## In player class

```
public State getState(){

if(b2body.getLinearVelocity().y >0 || (b2body.getLinearVelocity().y < 0 && estadoAnterior == State.JUMPING))
    return State.JUMPING;
else if(b2body.getLinearVelocity().y<0)
    return State.FALLING;
else
    return State.STOPSTATE;
}
```

in my case, if the player is falling and press jump button he will jump, but you can create more states like you want

Comment: Thank you so much for your great and exhaustive answer! You helped me a lot.